# Algorithm to find primes up to $n$ in $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Consider the problem of given an integer $n$, generating a list of the primes not greater than $n$. An optimized version of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) can do such task in $O(n)$, while the more modern [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) can do it in $O\left(\frac{n}{\log\log n}\right)$. (In both cases I assume that integer operations (sum, multiplication, modulo...) can be done in $O(1)$). My first question is:

> Are asymptotically better algorithms currently known?

Now, concerning lower bounds on such an algorithm. Of course we need at least $\frac{n}{\log\,n}$ operations (because this is asymptotically the number of primes up to n). So:

> Are there any reasons or heuristics that indicate whether an algorithm that does so in $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ should or should not exist?

Of course $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ should be really hard to achieve by traditional sieve methods, that usually involve writing down the numbers of a set asymptotically greater than the primes, and then sieving the non primes (I can't even think of an "easy to compute" set with size $O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ that contains the primes). But can a more convincing heuristics or at least an absurd implication of the existence of such an algorithm be given?

Comment: Have you tried asking it on the main SE site?

Comment: You should take a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05240)

Comment: I have a hard time believing that the Sieve of Erestosthenes runs in $O(n)$ time. There is a simple reduction from this problem to the problem of determining whether the number $n$ (given as input) is prime. The AKS primality test was the first deterministic poly-time algorithm to do this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) and runs in time $O(n \log^{6}n)$. This won a Godel prize. Maybe you mean to add some kind of memory constraints as well?

Comment: @mm8511 it is indeed more efficient to find all the primes up to $n$ altogether via a sieve than to test primality for each individually

Comment: @mm8511 You have confused two different $n$s: the sieve of Eratosthenes generates all the primes up to $n$ in $O(n)$, while AKS tests primality of an $n$ **bit** number (i.e. up to $2^n$) in $O(n \log^6 n)$.

Comment: Sieve of Sundaram might compare?